# Theme save png Access Denied

Tags: codenameone

I am using codenameone on windows 10 as aplugin on netbeans 8.2 .
I cannot save png image as simple Image with error access denied. I can save only as multiimage.
I would like to save it as simple image because of the smaller size of the application.

Do I have to setup something?

After Shai Almog suggestion I am posting the screehshot of the error

[image]
 and the the output of command line tool:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: res\theme\eiep-logo.png (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.writeToFile(EditableResources.java:865)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.saveXMLFile(EditableResources.java:955)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.saveXML(EditableResources.java:1474)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorView$SaveResourceFileAction.exectute(ResourceEditorView.java:4355)
    at com.codename1.ui.resource.util.BlockingAction.run(BlockingAction.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Add Image in the designer works for me. What's the error, can you include a screeshot? 
What's the output of the tool in the command line https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html

Comment: see updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck the XML Team Mode option in the File menu of the designer tool to workaround this.

The question is why is that file missing from the directory, did you remove/prune files from that directory?